# Button and mobile text can't be fixed

Tags: java, android, button

I made a dialer watching a video.
But there are two errors that can't be fixed, can you help me?
I can't upload the image, so I'll upload this:

```
package cn.itcast.phone;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class PhoneActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener());
    }
   private final class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
         public void onClick(View  v)
        {
            findViewById(R.id.mobile);
            String number = mobileText.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent ();
            intent.setAction("androi.intent.action.CALL");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The errors are in the 13rd and 19th line. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You had made all the coding mess...
Do as follows:-

```
public class PhoneActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

Button b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button);
TextView mobileText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Mobile);

b1.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListner{
 public void onClick(View  v)
    {

        String number = mobileText.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent ();
        intent.setAction("androi.intent.action.CALL");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}}
```

Try this this will help you for sure..

Answer (score 0):

You messed up the code a bit. This should work and you will be happy ;-)

```
public class PhoneActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final TextView mobileText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobileText);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View  v){
            String number = mobileText.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent ();
            intent.setAction("androi.intent.action.CALL");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but i copied all the code to the Activity, but it don't function.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class PhoneActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
final TextView mobileText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobileText);

//read the view id.
Button callButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

//assign listener for that button.
callButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View  v){
        String number = mobileText.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent ();
        intent.setAction("android.intent.action.CALL");
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
}
```

it will works.

Comment: Sorry, but i copied all the code to the Activity, but it don't function.